# Rails need advice on best practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need advice with Rails best practices. Actually in my application, for my `cars_controller` and my `contacts_controller` I need to load datas (below) for both controllers in `new`, `create`, `edit` and `update` actions :

```
@countries        = Country.all
@types            = Type.all
@departments      = Department.all
@models           = Model.all // This one is only needed on contacts_controller
```

Those gonna be populate into select box. Since I need to repeat it on each `new`, `create`, `edit` and `update` actions, I created a `load_resource` into my `application_controller` :

**application_controller.rb**

```
def load_resources
  @countries        = Country.all
  @types            = Type.all
  @departments      = Department.all
  @models           = Model.all // This one is only needed on contacts_controller
end
```

However, it really feel dirty to me as, what if I want to load other data for other controllers? I would like to know if there is best practicies for that?

I tried using a Presenter pattern but since those datas are not particularly attached to anything since they are just data in select box, it really didn't work.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see two possible improvements, firstly you don't need to load the resource on every action, secondly you can use caching to improve performance.

### Don't load resources on every action

Assuming your are following the standards REST conventions, if these resources are for your dropdowns, you don't need them in `create` and `update`. You only need them in `new` and `edit`, since only these two actions display a page to the user. `create` and `update` are the actions invoked by your form and would redirect to some other page.

Instead of adding it to your `application_controller`, I would just add a `before_filter` to your `contacts_controller` and `cars_controller`

**contacts_controller.rb**

```
before_filter :load_resources_for_dropdowns, :only => [:new, :edit]

def load_resource_for_dropdowns
  ....
end
```

### Use Caching

Also, if you are concerned about the performance impact of loading the resources from the database, you can consider using caching for it. For example, if your countries list never changes, you can safely do the following:

**country.rb**

```
def get_all_cached
  Rails.cache.fetch('all_countries') { Country.all }
end
```

**contacts_controller.rb**

```
before_filter :load_resources_for_dropdowns, :only => [:new, :edit]

def load_resource_for_dropdowns
  @countries = Country.get_all_cached
end
```

If your countries does change, you can add a check to clear the cache whenever something changes:

**country.rb**

```
after_save :clear_cache

def clear_cache
  Rails.cache.delete('all_countries')
end

def get_all_cached
  Rails.cache.fetch('all_countries') { Country.all }
end
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it's indeed a little bit faster and cleaner as well

Comment: Actually I still need it on `create` and `update` because when I'm making any validation errors, I need to render the action `new` or `edit` and it needs it in order to render it again